# html and css files are in the same folder but not being used

Tags: html, css

so I have the code below that links the css file to my HTML file but the HTML file is not using that style.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Animals are Awesome!</title>
  <link href="indexstyle.css" rel ='stylesheet'>
</head>
```

is there something formatting wise that I am doing wrong?
I also tried `href = './indexstyle.css'`

Comment: Do you really have a space after rel? What does indexsryle.css look like? How do you know it's not working? What is your browser dev tools saying?

Comment: Got rid of the space, and its not working cause I can obviously see that it is not styling? and just to test it I have p{color: green;} but when I enter my paragraph it is not in the green color

Comment: Did you check the browsers dev tools? Did it give an error loading the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I believe is due to the use of **href**

href linking is the method for including an external style sheet on your web pages. It is intended to link your page with your style sheet. Whereas importing allows you to import one style sheet into another.

Use:

```
<style>
@import url(YOUR/FILE/PATH)
</style>
```

---

Its good practice to place css files in a subfolder located within the folder your html is stored. This subfolder is labelled **static**

e.g.
main folder

> > index.html

static

> style.css

where **static** is located in **main folder**

I usually then import the file:

```
<style>
@import url("static/style.css")
</style>
```

(This goes within style not head)

Comment: I don't know what it was and I tried everything. Eventually I ended up just deleting that file and starting all over again yet this time it worked :/